# Populate no.of days in html table

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to Calculate and populate no. of days between two input dates in an Html table row by using javascript?
I have an understanding of Html, javascript, jQuery

I am a new programmer and I stuck on this step please help me out 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you include some of the relevant code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
function datesDiff(d1, d2){return (new Date(d1)-new Date(d2))/(1000*60*60*24)}
```

example usage:

```
datesDiff('03/12/2019', '02/12/2019'); //output 28
```